# Php, virtual database server for testing

Tags: php, mysql, database, unit-testing

So, I need to write tests which depends on database. For example:

```
function testme()
{
    $record = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM db'));
    return $record[0] + 1;
}
```

but this needs a real database, connection etc. Of course, I could create a "test" database, and set the connection - but why a "real" database is need? I must fill the test database too, can't it be easier? Sy, I just pass an array containing records.
EDIT: of course, I know it may be "tricky", that engine should emulate JOIN-s too, etc

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can use an array...but you'd need to populate that somehow, anyway. And that won't let you test your database, which is a crucial part of the process.

If you want to test the rest of your code using an array to narrow down the choices if something goes wrong, that's great, but then the next step should be populating your database and testing with that.

Comment: yea, but not everybody understood my question (those who voted me down). In Java, there are ODBC drivers, etc. Ideally, a virtual database server would be the best, not a cloned database

Comment: I'm not really understanding what you want to accomplish with that. A "fake" database would just be another database. Or do you mean something different than that?

Comment: A fake "sql server". Imagine that code without an installed MySQL

Comment: I see. That's a little odd, since like I said you'd need to populate the data either way.
If you really require a different way, you could use store your fake data in an excel spreadsheet and then use http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpexcelreader/
or http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/ to read that data.   
You could also make a CSV file of your data (comma separated value, which PHP could open easily: 
https://www.codedevelopr.com/articles/reading-csv-files-into-php-array/  
These courses of action will still require effort, but these options would be less work than setting up MySQL.